# includes in php

Tags: php, file, include

I include many pages inside each other in my project, I face problem of incorrect paths inside the include, is there any way to include the file from the root,
I try to make like this

```
require_once("$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/crm/includes/opendb.php");
require_once("./includes/opendb.php");
require_once("../includes/opendb.php");
require_once("includes/opendb.php");
```

and all makes error in includeing the file, any suggestion plz?

**Edit**

I have 2 folders, controllers and includes, inside the controller I call opendb.php from includes folder, I make as demonstrated in an answer below

```
set_include_path('../includes/');
include 'opendb.php';
```

and

```
set_include_path('includes/');
include 'opendb.php';
```

but the same error

```
Warning: include(opendb.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\AppServ\www\crm\controllers\Customer.controller.php on line
```

Comment: Isn't `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` root enough?

Comment: Actually, it should trigger a parse error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING`. Have you configured PHP to display errors?

Comment: These errors occurs many times besides to the warning above.

Comment: A tip for the future: if you get a parse error you cannot fix, ask explicitly about it and **paste** the actual error message in the question. A parse error means that your PHP code is not even valid. There's no point in improving the *logic* of a code that will not even run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/crm/includes/opendb.php"` is incorrect: you can't use apostrophes around array keys inside double quotes. Try one of these:

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/crm/includes/opendb.php" );
require_once( "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/crm/includes/opendb.php" );
require_once( "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/crm/includes/opendb.php" );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions (from [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to [class autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)) but I think that setting absolute paths is what tends to work better in practice: it's simple, intuitive and can't be easily ruined by sysadmins and third-party libraries.

You don't say why `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` does not work for you but I've found that it only works 99% of the times: some hosting providers do not set it or set it to a wrong value. Also, it's possible that the application is not directly in the document root. To overcome this, I normally write a `settings.php` file that's loaded *manually* on top of all scripts:

```
// One of...
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/conf/settings.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../conf/settings.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../conf/settings.php');
```

In `settings.php` I create two PHP constants:

```
define('FS_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/my-app/');
define('WEB_ROOT', '/my-app/');
```

I prefer constants over variables because they're available in all scopes (and they are constant values anyway). When setting their values, you can use as many logic as you want (for instance, you can calculate the `my-app` part rather than hard-coding it) but that's the general idea:

```
require_once(FS_ROOT . 'utils/email.php');
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . WEB_ROOT . 'js/validate.js"></script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [set_include_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to change the include path.

Let's say you have this document structure:

```
php/include.php
php/include2.php
file.php
```

And `php/include.php` has this code:

```
include 'include2.php';
```

If you were to include `php/include.php` in `file.php` like this:

```
include 'php/include.php';
```

It will cause an error on `include2.php` because you are not in the `php/` folder.

But if you do this:

```
set_include_path('php/');
include 'include.php';
```

It will work.

Comment: Try: `set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__)."/../includes/"));`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess that file `includes/opendb.php` is configuration for connection to the database?

If I'm right then it will be better for you to use OOP and MVC to separate view and logic and try to look for dependecy injection container (DIC) for configuring services, etc.

After that you will be able to use autoloaders for PHP classes and make changes in templates (include another templates, etc). This will prevent you from annoying `require_once("includes/opendb.php");`.

Answer (score 0):

If `$_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ]` doesn't work (it doesn't on some configurations like PHP+IIS) use one of the tricks below whichever works:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace( '\\', '/',
       substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, 0-strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
```

or

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace( '\\', '/',
     substr(str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']),
     0, 0-strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
```

To address files relatively use `dirname(__FILE__)`:

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/../includes/opendb.php' );
```