# Including header php file to my index php file - No error generated

Tags: php, javascript, html, dreamweaver

This may seems to be a silly mistake or my sheer ignorance about PHP basis. I have read some other question on stackoverflow regarding the same problem I'm facing, but it didn't help me much.

[includes in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994231/includes-in-php)

[unable to Include Files php using include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901993/unable-to-include-files-php-using-include)

My problem:

I am trying to include a header.php file which is located in my "include folder" onto my index.php file which is in the root folder.

index.php file content:

```
</head>

<body id="page1">
    <!--==============================header=================================-->
    <header>
        <?
        include("include/header.php");
        ?>  
    </header><div class="ic">
```

In the design view on Dreamweaver I can see the header is being included. However, when I am trying to see the page on localhost (WAMP server). I can't see the header is being displayed and I am not getting any error message either.

Comment: make sure the file's actually in place on the server. try a `require()` instead, which'd throw a fatal error if the file can't be included. if it's a shorttags, you'd be able to see the php code in your browsers "view source".

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `<?` but `<?php`

Depending on how your Apache is configured that might not work. Avoid short tags always.

Comment: Gotcha. I tried and it worked. However, just for my knowledge how can someone configure Apache so that it can recognize short tags.

Comment: You are always better using full tags. If tomorrow you upload your programme to another server, you don't want to waste time changing the apache config file (in case you want) or editing all your files and replacing the short tags. Full tags are universal, and universal is good.

Comment: Yes, short tags are evil. Listen to @ikaros45 that said, it s php.ini directive: [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Comment: As @ikaros45 pointed out, universal is the best method. When I started out with PHP, I used short tags and came across many 'complex' problems that can be avoided by just adding 'php' onto your tag!